# void pointer finding frequently occurrence of elements

Tags: c++, void-pointers

Before starting to write code of my project, I need to get advices. It is about finding frequently occurrence of elements(mode). The elements can be in `int`, `char`, `any object of class/struct` array. So, I have to use `void*`. I have a function that returns first occurrence of the mode element. i.e.

```
int arr[] = { 1, 7, 2, 4, 4, 8, 4 }
mode is 4
> return value 3
char arr[] = { 'q', 'w', 'w', 'u', 'u', 'w', 'o' }
mode is w
> return value 1
myClassObj[4];
myClassObj[0].mySetter(0,4);
myClassObj[1].mySetter(1,1);
myClassObj[2].mySetter(1,1);
myClassObj[3].mySetter(7,9);
> return value 1
```

Should I sort any kind of array to find mode? Should I use map library? What should I do, how can I start?

```
int indexOfFirstMode (const void * base, int num_of_elements, int size_of_arr, 
                      bool (*checker) (const void *, const void *));
```

**Edit:**

I shouldn't use `template` for now

Comment: It looks like you are only given a function to compare two elements for equality, so I don't think sorting or using maps will always be possible.

Comment: Is this about C or C++?

Comment: _"So, I have to use void*"_ You are mistaken. You should be using `boost::variant`. That is, assuming your code is _actually_ C++. Why did you tag it C?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have edited. I should write the code according to the prototype

Comment: so your `checker` function will be the same no matter what is the data type in the array ?

Comment: can be in `int`, `char`, `any object of class/struct` array. I should have three different function to compare. like strcmp @Mhd.Tahawi

Comment: @askque, I am sorry if my question was not clear, I was askign about the checker function. do you use the same function as a checker for all three cases ? or you have a different one for each case?

Comment: if I have for int `checkerint`, double `checkerdouble`, object `checkobject`, I will pass them using the checker function. So, as function pointer. Yes @Mhd.Tahawi

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can use templates technique instead of `void*`. This makes the solutions much easier:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template <class T>
int indexOfFirstMode(T array[], int size, bool (*checker)(const T& a, const T& b))
{
    int index = -1;
    int max_num = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int value = array[i];
        int num = 1;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            if (array[j] == value)
                num += 1;

        if (num > max_num)
        {
            index = i;
            max_num = num;
        }
    }

    return index;
}


bool checker(const int& a, const int& b)
{
    return a == b;
}


int main()
{
    int A[9] = {15, 3, 5, 7, 3, 1, 5, 5, 5};

    cout << indexOfFirstMode(A, 9, checker) << endl; // 2

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is it just for int type? Also, I wanted to idea but thanks for the code. I think it will not work for class

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is almost never a good idea to use `void *` in C++; There is always a better way.
The problem with `void *` is that they give you only the starting point of an object in memory but they won't tell you how much you should go from there (i.e offset).

in your case you can avoid that, since you have `num_of_elements` and `size_of_arr` you can calculate the offset, and since you are writing a different checker for each type, the checker function is aware of the size of the object you need to compare.

For calculating the mode, there are several ways to do that. you could sort the list and then look for the element with the longest run, another way to do it is to use a `std::map`mapping each elements to its number of occurrences and then taking the max.

but be careful, implementing that with `void *`is a bit tricky and you will need to be extra careful. 
Hope this helps.